# Discord.py - Py-Cord Mi bot no le da permisos de leer tickets, que puede ser?

Tags: python, discord.py

**Hola, tengo un problema; Se supone que cuando se crea un ticket, el que reacciono al boton debe poder ver el canal, pero no puede verlo, ya que el bot no le da permisos como para verlo, pero en el overwrites lo especifico ¿como podia arreglarlo? gracias**

En el overwrites especifique explícitamente que guild.me que es la persona que reacciona a la interaccion del botón, debe poder ver el canal que crea, pero no, no puede verlo

```
@bot.slash_command(name="tickets", description="Mensaje de tickets", guild_ids=[932788066207297586])
async def tickets(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("Enviando sistema...")

    channel = bot.get_channel(932862002261553194)
    message = """
    
    Crea un ticket para recibir soporte

    :white_small_square: Abusar de este sistema, sera penalizado con una sancion permanente
    """ 

    button = Button(label="Abrir ticket", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, emoji="")


    async def button_callback(interaction):
        try:
            sid = interaction.user.id
            cluster = MongoClient("censored")
            db = cluster["tickets"]
            collection = db["ticketids"]
            collection.insert_one({"_id": sid})

            overwrites = {
                guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
                guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, read_messages=True),
                ticket_mod_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
            }


            channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"{interaction.user.name}", overwrites=overwrites, category=bot.get_channel(933012520506126386))
            await channel.edit(topic=f"{interaction.user.id}")
            await channel.send(f"{interaction.user.mention}")

        except:       
            await interaction.message.respond(f"{interaction.user.name}, ya tienes un ticket creado!", ephemeral=True)
        

    button.callback = button_callback
    view = View()
    view.add_item(button)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Soporte", description=message, color=0X52b788)

    await channel.send(embed=embed, view=view)
```

Comment: tienes algún error por consola? el bot tiene permisos?